# Does the First Order control all of what's left of the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In many of the EU/Legends works, after Palpatine's death the Empire fragmented, many systems/sectors controlled by various Imperial officers turned warlords- is the First Order one faction of many or are all Imperials loyal to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TFA Visual Dictionary has this to say:

> The Galactic Concordance defanged the Empire's ability to wage war, with strict disarmament treaties and punishing reparations. **The Old Empire withered away, becoming a remnant of political hardliners locked in a cold war with the New Republic, before eventually breaking away to reform in the Unknown Regions as the mysterious First Order**.

This sounds like First Order controls all of Galactic Empire's **remaining supporters** (in other words, no other Imperial factions).

Obviously, they don't control all of Galactic Empire's old territory, or old population:

> Hux was a child when the Empire surrendered to the New Republic with the signing of the Galactic Concordance. His father fled the Academy on Arkanis, and was **one of the Imperials to make the exodus into the Unknown Regions, which the Empire had secretly begun exploring**. Hux grew up hearing legends of great Imperials, and how the Empire saved the galaxy from the violence of the Clone Wars.